# Não puxa o determinado valor da Array

Tags: angularjs

Estou com um pequeno problema no AngularJS

Preciso puxar os valores da array

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.data = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: [{
      d: "z",
      e: "4"
    },{
      d: "z",
      e: "4"
    }]
  }];  

}]);
```

Html

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
           <p>Não puxa: {{i.c.d}}</p>
           <p>Puxando o Valor: {{i.c.0.d}}</p>
 </div>
```

E infelizmente não consigo puxar.
Segue Link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jdym3w7eT0KSMZAD72V4?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tire o colchete do elemento `c`, afinal você quer acessá-lo como objeto e não como *array*.

```
$scope.data = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: {
    d: "z",
    e: "4"
  },
  {
    d: "z",
    e: "4"
  }]
}];
```

Comment: Boa tarde, tudo bem?
Quero que de um loop no {{c.d}}

E dessa forma da Erro..
Segue meu link http://plnkr.co/edit/Jdym3w7eT0KSMZAD72V4?p=preview
Obrigado.

Comment: Você tem uma estrutura bastante inconsistente. Começa com um `array` de 1 único elemento, esse elemento que está dentro possui alguns atributos, sendo horas novos `arrays`, horas possuindo um valor ou ainda sendo um novo elemento. Está ciente disso? Aqui tem uma sugestão de como melhorá-lo um pouco, ou ao menos conseguir iterar até o nível `c`: http://plnkr.co/edit/OcYQ3HJiMlSYNCm1a7nK

Comment: Outra sugestão, use chave/valor para iterar um objeto, desde que esse seja realmente um objeto, exemplo para a sua origem de dados: http://plnkr.co/edit/W2zyCulaZtrbODPlnK42

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver dessa forma:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data">
   <p>Não puxa: {{i.a}}</p>     
   <p ng-repeat="day in i.c">Puxando o Valor: {{day.d}}</p>       
</div>
```